# Error after WorkplaceXT Deployment On WAS 8.5

Tags: java, filenet-p8, filenet, filenet-workplace

I am getting error after workplace XT Deployment on WAS 8.5.
Filenet Env. is :
Filenet p8 5.2,
AD DS,
Windows server 2008.

ERROR is:

```
java.lang.StackOverflowError
 at java.lang.ThreadLocal$ThreadLocalMap.access$000(ThreadLocal.java:254)
 at java.lang.ThreadLocal.get(ThreadLocal.java:138)
 at javax.faces.context.FacesContext.getAttributes(FacesContext.java:57)
 at javax.faces.context.FacesContext.getAttributes(FacesContext.java:64)
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your code?

Comment: Actually I am getting this error after installation,configure and  deployment of WorkplaceXT  on WAS by deploying .ear file and this error is coming after first login for WorkplaceXT .I have configure WAS for WorkplaceXT.